# Image in UICollectionViewCell getting replaced by image in another Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

There is a scenario where I'm uploading images, PDF and YouTube URL to the server and after completion, these items are getting displayed in `UICollectionView`. The image is displayed as it is, for PDF an icon is there and for video, it's thumbnail. If I upload the image first then pdf and then YouTube URL, then in collectionView, the cell with pdf icon is replaced by the image. I'm using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) for downloading and caching images from the web.

Here is my collectionViewCell code.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.imageView.image  = nil
}

func configure(doc: GenericSubmissionDoc) {
    switch doc.type {
    case .document:
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Pdf-icon")
    case .image:
        self.imageView.setImageFromUrl(urlString: doc.url)
    case .video:
        self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        guard let thumbnailLink = doc.videoThumbnailUrl else {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "youtube")
            return
        }
        self.imageView.setImageFromUrl(urlString: thumbnailLink, placeHolder: UIImage(named: "Node-Placeholder"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are playing with async requests, I'd suggest you look at how you are populating the cell from inside the CollectionView, it might be that you are populating the same cell twice

Comment: umm nope, there is no scenario of populating cell twice, because it happens for very few times, most of the time it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to cancel the image download in `prepareForReuse` - just setting the image to `nil` will not do that.

Consider the following scenario:

- Cell is used as an `image` or `video` cell, image download is triggered
- Before the download finishes, the cell is reused as a `document` cell and you set the `Pdf-icon` image (the download from before is still running!)
- When the download finishes, it will replace the PDF icon with the downloaded image.